Djoser Login dosn't work with Docker-compose, Worker terminated with Signal 11
I am currently working in a data warehouse with Django and React.
For the Authentification is use Djoser, which worked really well when I don't deploy it with Docker.
When I Deploy it with my Docker-Compose I can Create(register) a User and Activate it but when I try to Login the Worker terminate itself with Signal 11. At the same time, when I use the wrong Password, I get 401 Wrong Password.
I'm pretty overwhelmed because it looks like it can access the DB (i use SQLite) because I can create the User.
First, I tried to log in with Postman because I thought it would be a Frontend Problem, but it's not.
Then I looked at the Network Timing on my browser, and it looks like it fails at the Initial connection when I use the right Parametes, with wrong Parameters the Request is ok without errors (just the 401)
When I turn on the Loggin feature it looks like this:
evse_v4_sprint-current-backend-1      | [2024-09-16 08:01:59 +0000] [33] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33
evse_v4_sprint-current-backend-1      | (0.001) SELECT "user_useraccount"."id", "user_useraccount"."password", "user_useraccount"."last_login", "user_useraccount"."is_superuser", "user_useraccount"."email", "user_useraccount"."name", "user_useraccount"."is_active", "user_useraccount"."is_staff", "user_useraccount"."is_creator" FROM "user_useraccount" WHERE "user_useraccount"."email" = 'me@mail.com' LIMIT 21; args=('me@mail.com',); alias=users
evse_v4_sprint-current-backend-1      | [2024-09-16 08:02:02 +0000] [32] [WARNING] Worker with pid 33 was terminated due to signal 11
evse_v4_sprint-current-backend-1      | [2024-09-16 08:02:02 +0000] [41] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 41

My backend Docker file looks like:
FROM python:3.10.6-alpine

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

#Set Work Direcotry
COPY . /app
COPY . /user
WORKDIR /app 
#ADD * /app

#Install Req
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt



COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/entrypoint.sh" ]

and my entrypoint.sh:
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --no-input

python manage.py migrate --database=users

python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

gunicorn settings.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000

My Frontend code to login is:
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    console.log("Try")
    try {
        
// TODO: process.env.API_URL: setzen
        console.log(body, config)
        const res = await axios.post(API_URL + `/auth/jwt/create/`, body, config);
        console.log(res)
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(load_user());
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Err")
        console.log(err)
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL
        })
    }
};

Here the web console log looks like:
Try
{"email":"mail@mail.com","password":"Passwort123"} {headers: {…}} headers:  [[Prototype]]: ObjectContent-Type: "application/json" [[Prototype]]: Object
ERR
B {message: 'Network Error', name*:* 'AxiosError', code*:* 'ERR_NETWORK', config*:* {…}, request*:* XMLHttpRequest, …}
the axios.post ends in a Djoser function, therefor i cant say anything

Not sure if anyone else need the answer for this question, but the soltion of the problem is to change ´FROM python:3.10.6-alpine´ to ´FROM python:3.10.6-slim´ so Alpine was the problem
